# using map to reformat objects in Array in JAVA SCRIPT

Tags: arrays, dictionary, reformatting

```
 const kvArray = [
          { key: 1, value: 10 },
          { key: 2, value: 20 },
          { key: 3, value: 30 },
        ];
        
        const reformattedArray = kvArray.map(({ key, value}) => **({ [key]: value }));**
        
        // reformattedArray is now [{1: 10}, {2: 20}, {3: 30}],
        
        // kvArray is still:
        // [{key: 1, value: 10},
        //  {key: 2, value: 20},
        //  {key: 3, value: 30}]
```

code
Java Script so In Java Script we have objects and are denoted by {}. eg {key:1, value:10} so in objects we have key value pair like key:1. key is named as key and its value is 1. similarly for value :10 key is named as value and its actual value is 10. and when we need to know the value of key we use [key]. So in above example where we have defined reformattedArray in the end we have used ({ [key]: value })) so why the value is not in [].
can some one help me with this?
when we need value from the Key we are using brackets[] but when we need the value from the element value  why are we not using brackets.

```
                what i know is when we need to get value we always use []
        the entries with in array are objects { key: 1, value: 10 } objects are represented as {key;value} pair so in { key: 1, value: 10 } for there are two elements key:1 and value:10 keeping in mind anything in objects are represented as {key:value} so in key:1 key is named as key and its value is 10 similarly key  and value in {value:10} are value and 10. So when we need to get the value of any key in object we use [key] which will return us the value of that key and should be same for [value] we will get value. so which in above example we are not using [ ] notation while retriving value 
        
        
                
                please help.
        
        
          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6zJ2.png
```

Comment: "when we need value from the Key" - what does that mean? Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Java Script
    
so In Java Script we have objects and are denoted by {}. eg {key:1, value:10} so in objects we have key value pair like 
key:1. key is named as key and its value is 1. similarly for value :10 key is named as value and its actual value is 10.
and when we need to know the value of key we use [key]. So in above example where we have defined reformattedArray in the end we have used ({ [key]: value })) so why the value is not in [].

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it**

Comment: "when we need the value from the value" - what does that mean?

Comment: edited in question does it make sense now ?

Comment: No, sorry. What do you mean by "value from the element value"? "what i know is when we need to get value we always use []" - what kind of question is that?

Comment: "why not ( {[key]:[value]} )" - why should the key itself be an array?

Comment: we use [..] notation to get the value of the key

Comment: What do you mean by that "[..] notation"? I've never seen that in JS. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Maybe a proper code example could help?

Comment: okay sir i will paste code from MDN and this is the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#using_map_to_reformat_objects_in_an_array

Comment: Can someone help me to understand? In above comment I have pasted the URL of MDN and you can find the above code in question there.